# How to type define destructured arrow function expression arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I am trying to do a little function that capitalizes the first letter of a word but typescript is giving me grief and I am not sure how to type define it.

Can you please help me type define this function:

`const capitalize = ([firstLetter, ...rest]) => firstLetter.toUpperCase() + rest.join('')`

Comment: A "word" is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bergi rightfully pointed out is that `string` is not an array.

So either you wish the user to call your method like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF3AQwA4Es6IDaoF4FNgBeYACgG0AoUUAM1QCd4AZPOOPegGiuuADoB9PPB4gAugC5g8eqigBzMmICUUmXPlEAfMDqM4LNhz5wIAVWTIOAYUQw8JZcADUwIfD4ArCHJIByP2UAblFgUMhYCEw8PkwIeRIwFHQsXAc-AFsAT2k4WQU-PhhkbDh-QOVgoA)

```
const capitalize = ([
  firstLetter,
  ...rest
]: string[]): string => firstLetter.toUpperCase() + rest.join('');

console.log(capitalize('my string'.split('')));
```

---

Either you use an other way to capitalize.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=38#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAHAlleAbZAvApjAvDABTQBOAXDGcmAOYCUl1dBAfFVKQHTo51QALGAH4O3CAFcARmSIAGADQwAjPS5QQAVUSIcpAMLwIOIvRgBqMV0kzORVTEoByJwG4AUO9CQQvHiFoiBBQ0TFwiJwBbAE8xGlonenpXIA)

```
const capitalize = (str: string): string => str.length ? str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1) : '';

console.log(capitalize('my string'));
```